# Ionic 3 - Unable to load API data on page

Tags: ionic-framework, cors

I am trying to follow the instructions on https://ionicacademy.com/http-calls-ionic/ and when I convert the call to my service (https://www.oakwoodnb.com/json/events.php), I am able to log the data to the console, but it won't display on screen.  Any idea why?

Here is my code:

api.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ApiProvider {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello ApiProvider Provider');
    }

    getVerses() {
    return this.http.get('https://www.oakwoodnb.com/json/events.php');
    }
```

daily-verse.ts

```
    export class DailyVersePage {

    //Added to retrieve verses
    verses: Observable<any>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:            NavParams, public apiProvider: ApiProvider) { 

    //Is this a race condition?
    this.verses = this.apiProvider.getVerses();

    this.verses
    .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('my data: ', data);
    })

    }
```

daily-verse.html

```
    <ion-list>
    <p ion-item *ngFor="let verse of (verses | async)?.results">
    Title: {{ verse.title }}
    </p>
    </ion-list>
```

The API I am calling does fail unless I have the CORS Chrome Extension enabled, but it does log to console when I have it turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer.  Posting it for those that may get stuck like I was.

I changed

```
    <p ion-item *ngFor="let verse of (verses | async)?.results">
```

to

```
    <p ion-item *ngFor="let verse of (verses | async)?.items">
```

because the data returns in the first element as "items" instead of "results" in the API.